# jQuery UI sortable issue

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, user-interface, jquery-ui-sortable

I am using the jQuery UI sortable widget. It's working fine at first. I have to populate the widgets dynamically from a database. Now it's only working in the presence of one particular widget with id `1`. If I delete that particular widget, it is not working anymore. Help me please.

Comment: write some code and also the plugin link

Answer (score 0):

If you are populating the data dynamically you have to re-initialize it after the data is added.jQuery uses regex to handle elements so when you change the HTML structure jQuery doesn't recognize any of the new data, try re-calling the sortable method after each ajax call